# How to handle Nuget dependencies in a project that uses the created package?

Tags: c#, nuget

The scenario is as follows:

I've created a package that uses JSON.net. I assumed since my package needs JSON.net to function, that this is a dependency. I've then added JSON.net as a dependency in the package metadata. I'm hoping I'm correct in that assumption so far.

The question/issue is as follows:
When using my created package in another project, downloading my package also downloads JSON.net which I assume is correct. This however leads to a reference to JSON.net in my project, attempting to use Resharper to optimize references flags this as an unused reference, as it's not directly used in the project. Is this a false positive report or have I some how skewed my dependencies? Given that all the usage of JSON.net is self contained in the package I've created and is not returned or exposed in my created package in any way.

Comment: There is a -IgnoreDependencies switch in the install-package command. But not sure thats what you want. you still need Json.NET in your build output and if you do not reference it you will need to copy it there some other way.

Comment: No, I don't want to ignore the dependency at all. I was just unsure why it would be tagged as an unused reference by Resharper if the assembly I referenced needed it.

Comment: well it is unused reference. If you remove it your project will still compile. Infact i think if you look at the output assembly metadata you will see that the Json.net is not included even if you referenced it, meaning that the compiler "optimized" it. But you still need it for the app to run, so i think you can just ignore the warning.